# How to "invert" integral function?

Tags: python, integral

I'm trying to calculate the blackbody spectral radiance using planck function:

[blackbody curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdVAl.png)

Then I integrated over the wavelength range (from 0.1 to 8.0) and I got a power of 3.22e7 [W]

Now, my problem!
I would like to do the opposite, just knowing the power value (and the temperature and the interested wavelength range) generate a curve as you can see on the plot above... do you have any solution how I can "invert" the integral?

Another question: Knowing the power, how can I extract the parameter T (temperature) from the inside of the integral?

Power = Int(planck function)

I can do it in Matlab in this way, but I don't know how to do it in python (Spicy?):

[matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJkew.png)

Thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be a math question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

The invert of an integral in a differential. I think you need to write (or find) a differential equation for this. Not sure for what you're using a power of 3.22e7 [W]. Could you write here exactly how you got your graph? I would ask in a comment, but don't have enough points for this.

Comment: Imagine the following equation:
P = int(8*pi/lambda * T^4)
"int" means integral between two ranges. 
I know all the values (P, lambda) except "T" and I would like to find the "T" value.

Comment: Which module do you use? Or is it a custom method?

Comment: I would like to use spicy or numpy if it is possible...

Comment: What have you already used to calculate the integral?